# access a variable from another class iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to access the value of a variable of another class in the iphone whithout using the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to access the variable if you write a getter method or if you synthesize the variable in the implementation.

See listing 5.2 in this document from Apple for an example. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/iPad/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: did that but it returns null when called by another class