# Access to an NSMutableArray element from another class

Tags: iphone, class, nsmutablearray

I'm writing a small program for iPhone.
I increase the array in the same class [MyArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: MyNumber]];. I would like to gain access to this element of the array in another class. Which way can I do?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527619) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+from+another+class+iphone).

Comment: take a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522141/how-to-passing-a-nsmutablearray-to-another-viewcontroller-class/6522480#6522480

Comment: @Vijay - your solution did not seem to be solving his problem, even though it was accepted...

Comment: possible duplicate of [access a variable from another class iphone development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527619/access-a-variable-from-another-class-iphone-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this in your first class aArray = [[NsmutableArray alloc]initwithobject:yourobjectname mutablecopy]; set property of that nsarray to this class .now you can access this variable to other class